Getting error pglogical.alter_subscription no such function
I am trying to set up bidirectional replication in Postgres in Docker.
I am using postgres 16.4 and used pglogic 2.4.4.
When I execute below in docker I am getting below error.
docker exec -it postgres-us psql -U user -d dbname -c "SELECT pglogical.alter_subscription('subscription1', synchronize_structure := true, synchronize_data := true, forward_origins := '{}', apply_delay := '0', conflict_resolution := 'last_update_wins');"

ERROR:  function pglogical.alter_subscription(unknown, synchronize_structure => boolean, synchronize_data => boolean, forward_origins => unknown, apply_delay => unknown, conflict_resolution => unknown) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT pglogical.alter_subscription('subscription1', synchro...
               ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

As per postgres document and pglogical it supports alter_subscription() and conflict_resolution but I am getting above error.
Can any one please suggest how can I set up postgres bidirectional for specific tables with conflict_resolution := 'last_update_wins'.
I am expecting data to flow only for specific tables mentioned in replication_set
